# Reduce data by summing and averaging certain variables in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr

My data looks like below.

```
id     MONTH    DAY      VAR1      VAR2     VAR3   ...
 1      10       21        5         1       "a"
 1      10       21        4         2       "a"
 1      10       22        3         4       "b"
 1      11       25        5         1       "a"
 2      10       10        5         1       "c"
 2      10       10        7         5       "c"
 2      10       28        5         1       "a"
 ...
```

From the data, If id,MONTH,DAY are same such as 1st and second row, I want to get sum VAR1 and mean VAR2, otherwise remain. Therefore my desired result should be

```
id     MONTH    DAY      VAR1      VAR2     VAR3 ...
 1      10       21        9        1.5      "a"
 1      10       22        3         4       "b"
 1      11       25        5         1       "a"
 2      10       10       12         3       "c"
 2      10       28        5         1       "a"
 ...
```

VAR3 is the same if id,MONTH,DAY are same. 
I think I can use aggregate repeatedly for each sum and mean function but it seems to be cumbersome. Is there a simple way of doing by keeping my data format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, MONTH, DAY) %>%
  summarise(VAR1 = sum(VAR1), VAR2 = mean(VAR2), first(VAR3))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
#Groups: id, MONTH [?]
#
#     id MONTH   DAY  VAR1  VAR2 first(VAR3)
#  (int) (int) (int) (int) (dbl)      (fctr)
#1     1    10    21     9   1.5           a
#2     1    10    22     3   4.0           b
#3     1    11    25     5   1.0           a
#4     2    10    10    12   3.0           c
#5     2    10    28     5   1.0           a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily do multiple calculations within a group with `data.table`, e.g.:

```
DT[, ("VAR1.sum", "VAR2.mean") := .(sum(VAR1), mean(VAR2)), by = .(id, MONTH, DAY)]
```